# SSRS Deactive Input Parameter

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2012

I want to have a parameter Label "Hour" its Integer type and I have set Default Value "0". I want to make it de-active in SSRS report so that it is always blurred and faded out.

Unable to find a source and resolve it. Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you cannot deactivate the parameter, you can set the default and available values to 0, so there are no other available values for the user to choose from

[image]